# Concurrently check if stack is empty

Tags: java, multithreading

How do you ensure that between subsequent calls to **!stack.isEmpty()** and **stack.pop()** the stack is not accessed by different threads?

```
executor.submit(()->{
    File currentDirectory;
    while(!directoryToSearch.isEmpty()) {
        currentDirectory = directoryToSearch.pop(); 
        ....
    }
}
```

Wrapping:

```
while ((currentDirectory = directoryToSearch.pop()) != null)
```

in a try and catch block or creating a lock for an already synchronized data structure simply does not feel like a good solution.

The stack is filled before releasing n threads on it and does not get filled up again. The issue I am seeing is that at the last object multiple threads might pass the stack.isEmpty() check before one of the threads is able to pop one element resulting in an exception for all other threads.

Comment: You could always make your function synchronized by adding the keyword like so: public static synchronized int getCount()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using ConcurrentLinkedQueue.  It should be quicker than synchronizing and future proof (if you DID later decide to add items in a thread while you pulled them out it would just work).

Second choice: Just catch the exception and continue as though the stack had been empty.

This is faster than Synchronized because synchronized has a fairly serious penalty whenever you enter a synchronized block but exceptions only cause a speed problem when they are hit (which will only happen on threads that are not doing anything interesting anyway).

Exceptions may be a little quicker than the ConcurrentLinkedQueue but only a little.

Comment: Currently I implemented a synchronized method as Jean suggested but as this function is tied to file indexing, which is performed at every application launch, I would like to keep it as fast as possible to eliminate any noticeable delay. Therefor, I will try to catch the exception and compare how fast both approaches are. So far I always thought that try and catch blocks always hurting performances no matter if exceptions are thrown or not. Something new I learned today. Thank you.